# Xcode, Parse - get the latest entry only.

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, nsdate

Using Parse.com i want my up to fetch only the latest entry added to the object.

```
func updateTable(notification: NSNotification) {
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Names")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.               

                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(self.messages, forKey: "messages")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(self.sections, forKey: "sections")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(self.url, forKey: "url")

                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

                self.loadData()              
            }

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println(error)
        }        
    })                
}
```

Problem is, everytime the function gets called the latest entry gets duplicated, maybe there is a way to compare the time it got saved using NSUserdefaults with the createdAt object, but i don't know how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I used this method, i don't know whether it's the best practice or not, but it got the job done for me.

```
if updateTime.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate > self.time.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
```